# ¿Guardar datos en una variable de un array dentro de un while?

Tags: php, mysql

Realizo una consulta a la Base de Datos donde me trae un determinado números iniciales y unos finales que se guardan en los arrays $inicial y $final.
Recorro esos arrays mediante un while pero quiero que cada vez que se recorra el array el valor de $inicial se guarde en una variable temporal "$temp" para poder realizar una suma entre el valor de el recorrido anterior del while "$temp" y el valor actual del array $final, pero aun no se como guardar el valor anterior de un array en una variable.

```html
$resultado = $temp + $final;
```

mi código en el cual hago el procedimiento es el siguiente pero falta implementar la linea de la suma de la variables

```html
  <?php
    $consultaS = $conexion->query("SELECT * FROM generador2.`TALONARIO` WHERE `inicial` > 1800000");
    while ($filaS = $consultaS->fetch_array()) {
        $inicial=$filaS['inicial'];
        $final=$filaS['final'];
        //$resultado= $inicial + $final;                               
        echo "<tbody id='tbody' class='tbody'><tr><td name='elemento[]'><font size=2>" . $inicial . "</font></td>" . "<td><font size=2>" . $final . "</font></td>" . "<td><font size=2>" . $filaS['usuarioasigna'] . "</font></td>" . "<td><font size=2>" . $filaS['fechaasigna'] . "</font></td>". "<td><font size=2>" . $filaS['cedula'] . "</font></td>". "<td><font size=2>" . $filaS['estado'] . "</font></td>". "<td><font size=2>" . $filaS['recibido'] . "</font></td>". "<td><font size=2>" . $filaS['fecha_rec'] . "</font></td>". "<td><font size=2>" . $filaS['usuario_rec'] . "</font></td>" . "</tr>";                                           
    }              
?>
```

Comment: bro... deberias poner el codigo que llevas y asi te podremos ayudar mas facil

Comment: si pruebas: $resultado += $inicial + $final; .. quieres suma por fila o suma total de todas las filas?

Comment: Me sirvio!! era lo que buscaba y tambien la funcion de ese operador me parece muy interesante.

Comment: excelente, voy a responder en la sección de respuestas para que quede documentado para futuras generaciones xD

Answer (score 1):

Creo que deberías inicializar tu variable $temp antes del ciclo while, así:

```
$temp = 0;
```

Luego, dentro del ciclo, le vas sumando lo que quieres sumarle (que no me quedó del todo claro), por ejemplo:

```
$temp += $inicial
```

De esta manera no deberías tener problema en ir sumando algo a esta variable y mantenerla al finalizar el ciclo.

Answer (score 0):

Debes usar el operador de asignación combinado `+=`

Documentación oficial PHP: http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.assignment.php

```php
...
while ($filaS = $consultaS->fetch_array()) {
    $inicial = $filaS['inicial'];
    $final   = $filaS['final'];

    $resultado += $inicial + $final;
   ...
}
```